# WordPress, remove click to enlarge from php code

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, woothemes

I am running a child theme for WooTheme's Inspire & have had a mod made to product-image.php so the thumbnails change the main product image if the user clicks on them. 
I would however like the main product image to not enlarge when clicked on (Lightbox is unchecked within WooCommerce so this is obviously not going to do the trick). 
I'm guessing it's this line;

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );
```

I have been in touch with support - but they are completely unhelpful in this instance.
I'm not a php programmer, so don't know how to alter the above code to remove that 'click to enlarge' functionality - I'd imagine it may well be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this client side within your document ready jQuery function

```
   $('.woocommerce-main-image').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   })
```

From the jQuery docs:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.